# Sencha2 JsonP push variable to Panel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am upgrading my app from Sencha 1 to Sencha 2 due to the fact that it handles JSONP a lot better.

I have my app set up and need to find out how I can push my JSONP results.
Here is my JSON request

```
var tweet = Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
    params: {
        'include_entities': true,
        'screen_name': 'NynasBo',
        'count': 1
    },
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        Ext.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var tweet = i.text;
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the function I am trying to push it too.

```
var contact = Ext.define('Nynas.view.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'contactcard',

    config: {
        title: 'Contact',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        html: '' + tweet.success.tweet
    },
});
```

But currently if I view my app I just get a `undefined` response.
I have verified the query and also made sure that it works, by simpling switching this line from
    var tweet = i.text;
to
    console.log(i.text);

You can see it will have a verified result

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in an asynchronous environment, the callback will affect your value only after it has been used. So something like this should work:

```
Ext.define('Nynas.view.Contact', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'contactcard',

config: {
    title: 'Contact',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    html: ' '
},
});

var contact = Ext.create('Nynas.view.Contact');

var tweet = Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
params: {
    'include_entities': true,
    'screen_name': 'NynasBo',
    'count': 1
},
callbackKey: 'callback',
success: function(result) {
  contact.setHtml(result.data.text);
}
});
```

Comment: this solution does not seem to work, did you actually verify the code that it should work? you are passing something called tweet.data.text which will result in nothing since the response is (result) please make sure to leave a valid solution

Comment: Since I have no clue how your result is actually returning, or what your environment is, this wont be valid 100%. This should point you in the correct direction though...